# Compute Paths - Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I was seeing a implementation of dijkstra's algorithm and I didn't quite understand some parts of this code:

```
public static void computePaths(Vertex source) {
    source.minDistance = 0;
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);

    while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        for (Edge e : u.adjacencies) {
            Vertex v = e.target;
            double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + e.getweight();
            if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                vertexQueue.remove(v);      //How can I remove if I didn't add it first, and why do I need to remove?
                v.minDistance = distanceThroughU;
                v.previous = u;
                vertexQueue.add(v);        //Why is it add again?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I read about dijkstra's algorithm so I know the general logic but while I was seeing this implementation there was a few things that I didn't understand why they were done. Can someone please try to explain? Especially where I have the comments!

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. How are we supposed to know which parts of the code give you trouble?

Comment: "*I was seeing a implementation of dijkstra's algorithm*" - why not ask the author?

Comment: That's not a great implementation - `PriorityQueue.remove` is a slow operation and makes the code pretty slow overall. (`add` is obviously necessary because how else will you get to other vertices?)

Answer (score 1):

**To update the information of node v**

You want to update the information of node v that is stored in the priority queue because you found a shorter path to it.

Remove() function removes the node **if** it exists in the priority queue.

After that you update the information, then add it again with the updated information.